# Autoloading Problem with Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am trying to include [MagentoBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipMagentoBundle) into my Symfony2 app. After installing and configuring the bundle according to the README I received the following error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Liip\MagentoBundle\SessionStorage\MagentoSessionStorage' not found in .../app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1447

Yes, the bundle is added to the autoloader and to the appkernel. However I am not quite sure where to look next, since I am new to Symfony2 and seemingly installed everything accordingly.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated :) .

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code from autoloader and AppKernel?

Comment: I have posted the code github: https://github.com/liip/LiipMagentoBundle/issues/2#issuecomment-2186472

Comment: Clear your cache and try again ;)

Comment: I must have cleared my cache a 1000 times ...

Answer (score 0):

be sure to have this in your deps file

```
[LiipMagentoBundle]
git=http://github.com/liip/LiipMagentoBundle.git
target=/bundles/Liip/MagentoBundle
```

Then, manually remove cache

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

set the right :

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

and reinstall vendors

```
php bin/vendors install --reinstall
```

If it's still failing use a debuger and look what happend it the autoloader